# Sorting buttons on a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel

I have a FlowLayoutPanel that users add buttons dinamically.  I worked out the code to add the buttons on the panel, the problem I have now is that my buttons are not sorted by name. Instead the buttons show up in the order they were created.

How can I sort the buttons automatically once a new button is created? Can this be done, or am I using the wrong type of panel?

Here is an image of the panel with my buttons, this one appears sorted because it was the initial panel I created.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SetChildIndex method of the Controls' collection:

```
flp.Controls.SetChildIndex(button3, 1);
```